# how to avoid extra spacing in html code while copying html code by a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, django-templates

i created a copy button by which you can copy HTML code of a div but problem is that when it coppy inner HTML it also copy  spacing of that main HTML I want to copy that code and remove extra spacing

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.value = text;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}

function copyEvent() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("copy").innerHTML;
  copyToClipboard(elem)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"   onclick="copyEvent();"><iconify-icon icon="akar-icons:copy"></iconify-icon>Copy code</button></p>
<div id="copy">
 <div class="s-popover ws2 mtn2 p0"
                    id="products-popover"
                    role="menu"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="s-popover--arrow"></div>
                <ol class="list-reset s-anchors s-anchors__inherit">
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="/" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:2})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;public qa submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Stack Overflow</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Public questions &amp; answers</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="/teams" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:3})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;teams submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Stack Overflow for Teams</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Where developers &amp; technologists share private knowledge with coworkers</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="https://stackoverflow.co/talent" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:5})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;talent submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Talent</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">
                                Build your employer brand
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            
</div>
```

it copy the code with all the spacing and all but I want to avoid that even new line is there any way by which I can avoid that any idea and suggestion will be helpful there Is way
by writing like that but i am retrieve some information from database so i have to use django template tag which is not being copied and it create extra spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove whitespace and new lines using regular expressions. This solution involves the usage of four regular expressions:

```
// remove newline / carriage return
str.replace(/\n/g, "");

// remove whitespace (space and tabs) before tags
str.replace(/[\t ]+\</g, "<");

// remove whitespace between tags
str.replace(/\>[\t ]+\</g, "><");

// remove whitespace after tags
str.replace(/\>[\t ]+/g, ">");
```

You can use in your code like this:

```
function copyEvent() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("copy").innerHTML;
  
  elem = elem.replace(/\n/g, "")
    .replace(/[\t ]+\</g, "<")
    .replace(/\>[\t ]+\</g, "><")
    .replace(/\>[\t ]+/g, ">");
  
  copyToClipboard(elem);
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y6nde0gc/1/

I found this solution in this website:
https://jaketrent.com/post/remove-whitespace-html-javascript

Had to make a small change to the 4th regex to make it work (removed `$` character).

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not a copy issue. The code is added to the `textarea` with the space.
2. The space exists in your HTML, because you don't have everything in one line
3. Consider using `.trim()`

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.value = text.trim();
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}

function copyEvent() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("copy").innerHTML;
  copyToClipboard(elem)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"   onclick="copyEvent();"><iconify-icon icon="akar-icons:copy"></iconify-icon>Copy code</button></p>
<div id="copy">
 <div class="s-popover ws2 mtn2 p0"
                    id="products-popover"
                    role="menu"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="s-popover--arrow"></div>
                <ol class="list-reset s-anchors s-anchors__inherit">
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="/" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:2})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;public qa submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Stack Overflow</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Public questions &amp; answers</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="/teams" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:3})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;teams submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Stack Overflow for Teams</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">Where developers &amp; technologists share private knowledge with coworkers</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m6">
                        <a href="https://stackoverflow.co/talent" class="bar-sm p6 d-block h:bg-black-100 js-gps-track"
                            data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:5})"
                            data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;talent submenu click&quot;,null,null,null]">
                            <span class="fs-body1 d-block">Talent</span>
                            <span class="fs-caption d-block fc-light">
                                Build your employer brand
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            
</div>
```